# how to add new files to the last commit?

Tags: git

I'm new using git. I committed a project but forgot to attach a file. Searching I found the command `amend`.

To add the new file I do the following:

```
git add 'fileA.py" 
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

In my local folder I see the icon that the file was added. But when I go to the repository, the file does not appear.

It may be a very simple question, but I don't know if is necessary to make a push? or if I need to do something else.

Comment: "when I go to the repository" That's a serious misconception. The repository is on your computer. There is also a remote repository. They are not automatically synchronized; it's up to you to push / fetch between them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to push to the remote repository to see it. If you already had pushed that commit you amended, you will rewrite history so you'll have to force push

```
git push -f origin <your_branch>
```

---

If you work with other people on the same branch, make sure you don't delete someone else's commit by force pushing. You can use `git push --force-with-lease` to be warned if someone else pushed in the meantime and you have to `git pull` before pushing.

Comment: Yes, other people commit to the same brach (master). On some occasion when doing an -f origin the other commit of other people was deleted. What steps should I follow to avoid deleting anything from the other contributors?

Comment: Just what I said in my answer. Prefer using `--force-with-lease` to prevent force pushing when you are about to delete other people's commit and always try to pull remote commits before pushing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be simply to:

- add the file to the index
- make a new commit (instead of amending an existing one)
- pull --rebase (in order to replay your commit(s) on top of the most recent `origin/<yourBranch>`
- push (simple --push, no force necessary there)

That is:

```sh
git add forgottenFile
git commit -m "Add forgotten file"
git pull --rebase
git push
```

Comment: This is the better answer. The idea that you need to modify an existing commit is a misconception. All commits reflect the entire state of the project. Just make a commit reflecting the state you want to reflect, and push it.